# Form_for in a loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I'm generating a list of projects each with a form to add a new audition to that particular project. The form isn't being generated properly.

The view:

```
<% @projects.group_by(&:aasm_state).each do |state, projects| %>
  <div class="project-column small-order-<%= state_priority(state) %>">
  <div class="project-state spaced-out-2 project-<%= state %>"><%=  state.titleize %></div>

  <% for project in projects %>
    <%= render partial: 'auditions/partials/dash_project_audition_form', locals: {project: project} %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is the code in the partial:

```
<button data-click="new-project-audition">+ Audition for <%= project.title %></button>
<%= form_for([project, @audition]) do |f| %>
... SNIP....
<% end %>
```

Everything works except the form. Each form generated contains the ID for the last record in `@projects`. So, for example the last project is ID 19, no matter which project form I click on, they're all for 19. The problem isn't with the partial, it's with something I'm doing in `form_for`, because `+ Audition for <%= project.title %>`, which is inside the partial, generates the correct title.

UPDATE:
I restarted the server and form_for is now generating the right path, with the right ID.

I have this line also inside the form_for loop, and it's still wrong.
`<h3 class="section-head">New Audition for <%= project.title %></h3>`

It's generating the title for the last project in the whole loop.

UPDATE 2: Stopped working on a page reload, so... not even sure what to say now.

Comment: what is @audition set to in the controller ?

Comment: Audition.new -- should it be assigned in the loop?

Comment: I'd also tried passing it to the partial as a local `audition: @audition`

Answer (score 0):

when you do form_for([project, @audition]), it generates a form for

> projects:project_id\auditions:audition_id

so the id that you see in all forms may belong to the @audition variable. Where do you initialize it ?

It should be initialized ideally on a per project basis, right ? Let me know if this helps in any way.

Comment: the path is projects/project_id/audition -- since, the audition is new and has no ID yet (I'd started with `[project, audition]` but trying various things had just passed instance variable straight to the form_for helper on my last iteration.

Comment: `<form class="new_audition" id="new_audition" action="/projects/19/auditions" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">`

Comment: and audition, the variable passed to the partial = project.auditions.new right ? i mean, scoped per project right ?

Comment: I'm looking closer, the ID is definitely the project and not `@audition` -- because `project.title` in the partial generate the title of project 19. Also, @audition shouldn't need to be scoped to the project, because it's just initializing a new audition, right? Auditions are a nested resource so Rails should know how to handle that. I get an error changing the scope your suggesting.

Comment: It seems like the audition variable is probably the problem, right -- should I not set it in the controller so that the loop initializes for each project? I'm not sure how to do that in the controller otherwise.

Comment: it cannot be initialized in the controller since you're not using one instance of this variable.. ideally i think something like this should work..
<%= render partial: 'auditions/partials/dash_project_audition_form', locals: {project: project, audition: project.auditions.new} %>

can i know what error is being thrown ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/112722/discussion-between-littlecegian-and-slick23).